# Is downcasting in this situation acceptable?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, factory, downcast

I am currently part of a project creating a client-server model to automate a certain task. At a certain point in the project I had to perform downcast to do certain things. Generally, down-casting means your design is flawed. I raised this issue to my lead engineer but she said

> It is okay to downcast an interface to its derived class but not an concrete class

I didn't really understand her explanation. Without delving into major details, I will supply a pseudo code describing the actual project scenario. Please note the following is an close enough analogy.

We have a base class `UniversalAnimal`

```
class UniversalAnimal{
    private:
        Type type;
        Colour color;
        int weight;
        int legs;
        int wings;
        int fins;
        int fangs;   
        // other common attributes for all animals; getters and setters 
}
```

So the universal animal class is like a place holder class for any animal. Note, it has fins (fishes), fangs (snakes) and wings (birds).

There is a `AnimalFactory` class which returns a `GenericAnimal` `interface` based on the `Type`. For instance,

`GenericAnimal animal = animalFactory.getAnimal(uniAnimal)`

After getting a `GenericAnimal` from the factory; there are certain model specific methods to be called for further processing in the program. In order to call these specific methods, the `GenericAnimal animal` must be down casted to the corresponding derived class. For example;

```
class Snake implements GenericAnimal{
    int poisonLevel;
    int fangLength;
    int length;
    bool isPoisonous;

    void setPoisonLevel(int level){
       this.poisonLevel = level;
    }

    int getPoisonLevel const{
       return this.poisonLevel;
    }

    // other getters and setters
    // other methods overriding interface GenericAnimal
}
```

To set poison level to a snake;

```
UniversalAnimal uniAnimal = UniversalAnimal();
uniAnimal.setType(Type::SNAKE);
uniAnimal.setColour(Colour::BROWN);
uniAnimal.setFang(2);
uniAnimal.setFins(null);
//irrelevant attributes to snake like wings, fins are set to null by default

GenericAnimal gAnimal = animalFactory.getAnimal(uniAnimal);

if(gAnimal instanceof Snake)
  // checked downcasting
  Snake snake = (Snake) gAnimal;

snake.setPoisonLevel(3);
// call other methods specific to snake
}
```

Though this is an checked downcasting and will not throw a runtime exception; down-casting is generally means flaws in design. Also if the client who uses the factory needs know the type of the object then, I believe, using factory is a wrong design choice. Please give me insights and possible alternate design (if this design is wrong) for this problem.

Comment: This looks like a violation of the Liskov Substition Principle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Instead of downcasting, what about using the Strategy pattern to define logic for dealing with different types of objects (or Animals, in this case)?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. I need a POJO of the derived class further down in the project. So strategy pattern doesn't completely solve the problem.